# Is it known whether the boundary of the Mandelbrot set is not continuous?

Tags: continuity, curves, fractals, complex-dynamics

I might be missing something obvious here, but my understanding is that nobody currently knows whether the boundary of the Mandelbrot set is a Jordan curve because otherwise we would know that the Mandelbrot set were path-connected which according to Wikipedia we don't.  But what about the other way around?  Do we maybe know that the boundary is *not* a Jordan curve?  Or even that it's not continuous?

Comment: Real mathematicians don't mandelbrot.

Comment: @GregoryGrant: surely you don't mean that real mathematicians are inclined to avoid intractable problems $\ddot{\smile}$.

Comment: Real mathematicians wouldn't generally hate things like Mandelbrot sets, it's just that the popular press has given the public the impression that fractals are way more important than they are.  When I tell people I'm a mathematician, more often than not they say "oh yeah, fractals".  I'd prefer "oh yeah, elliptic curves".

Comment: @GregoryGrant: So, you are saying that someone like [Mitsuhiro Shishikura](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mitsuhiro_Shishikura) is not a real mathematician?  Hmm...

Comment: @Frunobulax Only if you equate fractal geometry with complex dynamics.

Comment: There's a was a [discussion of this on MathOverflow](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/48642/parametrization-of-the-boundary-of-the-mandelbrot-set), the main point of which is that the boundary can be paramtrized *if* the local connectedness conjecture is true.